# Compiling Firefox 50 under GLibc 2.12

Tags: centos, compiling, firefox, glibc, glib

I've successfully been able to `configure` the latest Firefox ([source](https://archive.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/)) without errors. All the required dependencies are in place (i.e. GCC 4.9.2 via devtoolset-3, Python 2.7, Yasm, libffi 3.2.1, and on). When I run `./mach build` it also successfully `configure`s and starts `make`ing the binaries... then after about 24 minutes it chokes on

```
24:40.15 /home/osboxes/firefox-50.0b7/gfx/thebes/gfxFontconfigFonts.cpp: In member function ‘virtual already_AddRefed<gfxFont> gfxPangoFontGroup::FindFontForChar(uint32_t, uint32_t, uint32_t, gfxFontGroup::Script, gfxFont*, uint8_t*)’:
24:40.15 /home/osboxes/firefox-50.0b7/gfx/thebes/gfxFontconfigFonts.cpp:1628:66: error: ‘g_unicode_script_from_iso15924’ was not declared in this scope
24:40.15        (const PangoScript)g_unicode_script_from_iso15924(scriptTag);
24:40.15                                                                   ^
```

The pertinent part being

> ‘g_unicode_script_from_iso15924’ was not declared in this scope

I searched online for this error first and the only reference to this is a fixed bug in v52 ([ref](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1306543)) which isn't even in the sources repo at this time. This isn't a bug.

How to compile Firefox 50 for a system using GLibc 2.12?

---

**Solved:** I discovered that `g_unicode_script_from_iso15924` is a **new symbol** in GLib 2.30 ([ref](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/api-index-2-30.html)). Glib needs to be updated to at least version 2.30.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a symbol in glibc, it's a symbol in [GLib](http://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GLib). If you build and install GLib 2.30 or later, you should be able to build Firefox 50.